# VS2017でリビルドやクリーンするとエラーになる「アクセスが拒否されました。」

Tags: visual-studio

Windows10、Visual Studio 2017の開発環境で、
ASP.NET MVC(.net47)のWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
プロジェクトをリビルドやクリーンしてbinフォルダ内のアセンブリが削除される際に
以下のようなメッセージでアクセス拒否エラーになってしまい困っています。
原因や解決方法が分かる方いれば教えてください。

OSを再起動したりサインインし直したりすると一旦は直る（削除されるようになる）のですが
しばらく使用していると、また同じエラーが出るようになってしまいます。

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4825,5): warning MSB3061: ファイル "" を削除できません。パス '' へのアクセスが拒否されました。`

アクセス拒否されるアセンブリ:

```
bin/roslyn/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
bin/roslyn/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
bin/roslyn/System.IO.Compression.dll
bin/roslyn/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
bin/roslyn/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
bin/roslyn/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
bin/roslyn/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
bin/roslyn/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
bin/roslyn/VBCSCompiler.exe
```

Comment: 同一事象ではないですが、プログラミング作業に際し、アンチウイルスソフトがファイル操作を妨げていたという経験が何度かあります。
もしアンチウイルスソフトをお使いでしたら、動作を停止してみたり、該当ディレクトリを監視対象から外したりしてみると解消されたりはしないでしょうか。